# How to use various bluetooth services of a smartphone through python?

Tags: python, bluetooth

My smartphone supports the following bluetooth services -

1. SDP Server
2. AVRCP Target
3. Dial-Up Networking
4. *OBEX Object Push     [known]*
5. Imaging
6. Phonebook access PSE
7. Hands-Free Audio Gateway
8. Headset Audio Gateway
9. SyncMLClient
10. Audio Source
11. AVRCP Controller
12. *OBEX File Transfer     [known]*
13. Nokia OBEX PC Suite Services
14. *Data Transfer    [known]*
15. Nokia SyncML Server

I want to use these services from python, but I don`t know to use any other than OBEX Object Push, Data Transfer and OBEX File Transfer.
How do I use the remaining services?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to connect from a PC to the smartphone?
Or do you have python installed on a smartphone?

By default PyBluez should help you use SDP as well. Have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/sdp-browse.py?r=1) for an example.

For imaging you could also use the RFCOMM (or SPP) to serialize the image and transfer it...

For the rest you might have to find something more solid than Python I think. Or wrap some native libraries to Python yourself.